# Convert a json object data to a json array data?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

How can I convert a json object data to a json array data? For instance,

I have this json object data from the server on my console on firebug,

```
Object { 0={...}, 1={...}, 2={...}, more...}
```

json string,

```
{
    "items": {
        "0": {
            "pub_name": "News",
            "system_id": "57",
            "make_accessible": "0",
            "count": "7",
            "router": "#/post/news/list/"
        },
        "1": {
            "pub_name": "upcoming events",
            "system_id": "134",
            "make_accessible": "0",
            "count": "7",
            "router": null
        }
    },
    "total": 2
}
```

And I need to convert it to,

```
[Object { pub_name="Main", system_id="50", make_accessible="0", more...}, Object { pub_name="estate", system_id="122", make_accessible="0", more...}, Object { pub_name="wines", system_id="125", make_accessible="0", more...}, 7 more...]
```

json string,

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "pub_name": "News",
            "system_id": "57",
            "make_accessible": "0",
            "count": "7",
            "router": "#/post/news/list/"
        },
        {
            "pub_name": "upcoming events",
            "system_id": "134",
            "make_accessible": "0",
            "count": "7",
            "router": null
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Note however that json has nothing to do with this. You'll need to iterate over the keys in your object, creating the desired array.

Comment: How would you be deciding on the object's element names? Where are you getting 'pub_name' and 'system_id'?

Comment: Just because this kinda bugs me, there is no such thing as a "json object" or a "json array".  Those terms are incorrect.  JSON is a transport format for data (similar to CSV or XML).  JSON is *always* a string.  It can *represent* an object or an array, but it itself is always a string.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.  What you have is a JavaScript object and a JavaScript array.  It may have been *parsed* from a JSON string, but it's not JSON.

Comment: Please see my edit above if it makes any sense?

Comment: or what do you call these two different types of 'json'?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: There are not "different types of json".  There are JSON strings.  JSON can be *parsed into* a JavaScript object and/or a JavaScript array.

Comment: I know there are not "different types of json". I just don't know how do u call it one with numbering and one without - if you look at the json strings in my question.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: One is an object, one is an array.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: How are you creating this JSON string in the 1st place? You might be able to have it be returned to you already in the right format.

Comment: All the data from the server are always returned as a std object and I think that is the problem. And then I convert the std object with `echo json_encode($items);`

Comment: So then I get the numbering json string - object which is what I am on about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be to fix how it is being generated serverside, possibly by converting the Items structure to an array in whatever server-side language you are using.

However, if javascript is your only option, all you need to do is iterate over the object keys assigning them to an array.

```
var jsonstring = '{\
    "items": {\
        "0": {\
            "pub_name": "News",\
            "system_id": "57",\
            "make_accessible": "0",\
            "count": "7",\
            "router": "#/post/news/list/"\
        },\
        "1": {\
            "pub_name": "upcoming events",\
            "system_id": "134",\
            "make_accessible": "0",\
            "count": "7",\
            "router": null\
        }\
    },\
    "total": 2\
}';

var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
console.log(data); // {items: Object, total: 2}

var tempArr = [];
for (key in data.items) {
    tempArr[key] = data.items[key];
}
data.items = tempArr;
console.log(data); // {items: Array[2], total: 2}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nje2e/

If you have jQuery included, you can use `$.makeArray()`;

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
console.log(data); // {items: Object, total: 2}
data.items.length = data.total; // adding a length makes it array-like
data.items = $.makeArray(data.items);
console.log(data); // {items: Array[2], total: 2}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nje2e/1/